# How to indentify a word in a input php?

Tags: php, input, cpu-word, identify

I want to know how I can identify a specific term or word in a input on php. Like if they write `<script>`, it will not be allowed to submitted. So that people don't hack my website.

So I need I code to see if that term or word it was written in the input. I mean, if the input was `jkgdknf <script> iofosef` I will like the program to not allow the guy to submit that input.

Thanks !

Comment: why not just use htmlspecialchars() on output? or strip_tags on input?

Comment: [These links](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=preventing%20xss) will help you immensely in learning how to prevent against attacks like this.

Comment: Don't "secure" your website this way!!! It will not be secure at all. Use htmlentities() or http://htmlpurifier.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing for that is [strip_tags()](http://uk.php.net/strip_tags):

```
$string = strip_tags($_POST['input']);
```

> *This function tries to return a string with all NUL bytes, HTML and PHP tags stripped from a given str.*

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlentities(). See [www.php.net/htmlentities](http://www.php.net/htmlentities)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `htmlspecialchars` to prevent your site from getting hacked and at the same time allowing user to enter whatever they wish